# Calculate the following integral: $\int_{0}^{2\pi }\sqrt{\cos^{2}t + 9\sin^{2}t}\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi }\sqrt{\cos^{2}t + 9\sin^{2}t}\,   dt$$

I used $\cos^{2}t + \sin^{2}t=1$ and $2\sin^{2}t=1-\cos2t$ so I got:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi }\sqrt{5-4\cos2t} \,  dt$$

but now I don't know how to continue with the solution.

Comment: This looks like the perimeter of an ellipse which usually cannot be determined exactly.

Comment: see [complete elliptic integral of 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: Wikipedia also explains how one might compute the circumference of an ellipse [on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference)

Comment: According to the google plugin, the answer is about $13.36$.

Comment: I had to calculate the length of the curve $(sint, 3cost)$ for these $t$, that's why I got the integral. I don't know why our teacher give us this exercise since I am on my second semester at university and I don't really know what "elliptic integral of 2nd kind" is.

Comment: There's no elementary way to compute the perimeter of an ellipse. You can only approximate it, but can't express the value in terms of the elementary functions (such as trigonometry functions or log functions).